# Tag inside for loop using lxml library

Tags: python, odoo, lxml, odoo-8, odoo-9

```py
from lxml import etree
def generate_header(self):
    root = etree.Element('TAG1',)
    for inv in self.env['account.invoice'].search([]):
        po_code = etree.SubElement(root, 'data').text = str(inv.id)
    return root
```

How can i add another tag inside for loop.  if i put root inside for loop then it generates xml file for 1 record. i need it to look like this.

```xml
<tag1>
   <tag2>
     <data>my data<data>
   </tag2>
</tag1>
```

with my code i'm getting

```xml
        <tag1>
             <data>my data<data>
        </tag1>
```

i just need same tag as tag1 just inside for loop

Comment: i updated my question hope it helps. the code is to huge to post it here, i tried to simplify it as much as i could.

Comment: Your code just puts tag 'TAG1' in root. 'tag2' is not put on your code. you need to put tag2 in new variable like this `tag2=etree.SubElement(root, 'tag2')` and change variable po_code to use tag2 instead of root `po_code = etree.SubElement(tag2, 'data').text = str(inv.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for any number of tags you want:

```
from lxml import etree

def do(n_of_tags, inner_tag_name, inner_tag_text, starting_tag_num=1):
    i = starting_tag_num
    # create root outside loop
    root = etree.Element('tag{}'.format(i))
    parent = root
    i+= 1
    while i <= n_of_tags:
        # append next tag to parent and make the new tag parent
        parent.append(etree.Element('tag{}'.format(i)))
        parent = parent.getchildren()[0]
        i+= 1
    # add your own tag to last parent with text
    etree.SubElement(parent,inner_tag_name).text = inner_tag_text
    return root

r = do(2,'data','my data')
# just to see if it works
with open('test.xml','wb') as w:
    w.write(etree.tostring(r,pretty_print=True))
```